# mapbasic convert raster to mrr

Tags: raster, mapinfo, mapbasic

I'd like to convert a whole folder of files from GRD to MRR. Is this possible in mapbasic or from the interface or do I need to do them file by file?

I have tried to searching in the mapbasic forums for code for mrr conversions but not found any and the mapbasic window does not show any code in MI Pro.

Comment: Do you want to convert them individually or merge them into a single MRR?

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller convert them individually thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MapInfo Raster API is .NET based so to do some scripting you need to write some .NET code like C# or VB.NET.

There are a number of sample files for the API in the MapInfo Pro installation folder under Raster\Documentation\API\Sample Code.

If you look into the sample called MapInfo.RasterEngine.Processing.Samples.cs you can find some examples on how to convert from one format to another.

It can be as simple as this:

```
public void Convert_Example_01(string strInFilePath, string strOutFilePath, string strDriver)
{
   // Default RasterApiOptions
   // FieldBandFilter is set to All Fields All Bands
   // RasterCreationOptions will be read from default user's preference file.
   // RasterFinalizationOptions will result in default settings.

   RasterProcessing.Convert(strInFilePath, strOutFilePath, strDriver);
}
```

The Convert method does take a number of other parameters to give you even more control over the process.

Most of the samples from the sample files can also be found in the Raster API Documentation: Raster\Documentation\API\MapInfoProRaster.NET_SDK.chm

Answer (score 1):

With Mapinfo Pro Advanced version 17.0, A batch processing feature has been added to Convert, Resample and Reproject operations. Using this one can easily select any number of GRD file and convert it to corresponding MRR files in an an output directory of choice in one go.